# What are the security risks of hardcoding username password in an angular 10 component?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, websecurity

I have a web app, frontend framework for which is Angular v 10. Dist folder generated by angular build is deployed in S3(public bucket used as a static website endpoint) behind Cloudfront and backend is handled serverless API Gateway > Lambda with Go. For the API Gateway endpoint calls from Angular I have AWS Amplify integrated and API Gateway authentication is through Cognito User Pools.

Everything works great but while setting up I realized that in my angular component I have hardcoded the username and password in the angular component like below for initial Amplify Auth calls to get the token to make backeend API calls. Is there a better and secure way to do this? If I code it this way as I found in most examples what are the security risks?

```
//starting Angular component code snippets    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-abcd',
  templateUrl: './abcd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abcd.component.scss']
})
export class AbcdComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

  idToken:string ='';
  error: any;
 
  

**//Any security risks here? What is the best practice to securely do this in Angular?
      userdata = {username : "uname", password : "passcode"};**


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    
    Auth.signIn(this.userdata).then(user => {
      if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'){
        Auth.completeNewPassword(user, "hello");
      }
      this.idToken=user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
      this.apiService.doTheThing(this.idToken).subscribe(res => {
        if (res!=null){
          console.log(res.response);
      }, error => this.error = error);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Is this any better if I store the hardcoded username and password in src/environments/environment and import it in the component and use it like this below.

src/environments/environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  username: 'hellouser',
  password: 'hellopasscodee',
};
```

In angular component

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

userdata = {username : environment.username, password : environment.password};
```

This works as well but I am thinking how are hardcoded strings any safer in environment.ts than any other angular-related component ts files?

Comment: Hardcoding unencrypted username/password is like not using username/password from a security point of view. You never should do something like that, but maybe in prototype environments.

Comment: Because it is easy to extract strings from an application source code or binary, credentials should not be hard-coded. This is particularly true for applications that are distributed or that are open-source.

Comment: This is not the ideal and high security risk. You need to communicate server to server, in short create a wrapper aws lamda service, that holds username and password in aws env, and it return the token to UI required for further API call. Also add strict CORS so others can't use it except your UI.

Comment: For solution, you can check this link.  
 https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/29/angular-9-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example